# Кнопка Undo для раскраски в Unity

Tags: c#, массивы, unity3d

товарищи программисты!
Уже неделю ломаю голову над задачей. Есть приложение - 3d раскраска. В нем для покраски объектов использую материалы из Resources, и скрипт использующий лучи (Ray). Задача такая - нужна кнопка отмены действия, нажав на которую цвет меняется на предыдущий. Объектов на сцене много, сцена как понимаете тоже не одна.

Что пробовал? Читал на форумах, что можно использовать лист/массив, и через скрипт добавлять в него примененные на сцене материалы. После этого при нажатии Undo спускаться по этому массиву вниз. Но моих знаний в c# не хватает, для меня это сложный код. Объектов много и я не понимаю как процесс окрашивания отслеживать. Создать для gameObject еще один массив? В общем запутался конкретно, выручайте.

P.S. все сценарии я с гореча удалил, даже показать свои дебри не могу(может и к лучшему))

Comment: Вам стоит обратить внимание на паттерн Command из GoF. Очень упрощенно: сохраняете каждую вашу команду в стек команд. Командой будет в вашем случае что-то вроде какой именно объект закрашивается (координаты и так далее), цвет окрашивания, цвет до окрашивания. В общем нужны полные данные, для отмены на предыдущее состояние.

А далее, когда нужно отменить - берёте элемент из стека и делаете для него обратную операцию.

Comment: Можете показать пример кода, как это может выглядеть в C#

Comment: Я прочел информацию о Command, для меня это еще более запутанно. С массивами то не могу до конца разобраться)

Comment: @sertsin вы сейчас спрашиваете как научиться читать слова, не выучив буквы) разберитесь сначала с основами. Ничего лучше паттерна Command для реализации Undo нет. Попробуйте поискать другие, более понятные объяснения. Однако, если вы ещё с массивами "не разобрались", то, возможно, вам просто следует начать с более простых вещей

Comment: @sertsin, кому лучше? Реализация Undo в Commnad в том числе включает и массивы. Вам уже сказали в какую сторону смотреть.